# Is there a phrase call "print news"?

Tags: word-meaning

The sentence from which it came:

> It is estimated that 30 percent of Americans already get their news from Facebook, a percentage which is likely to grow, considering that many young users are turning away from **print news**.

The original article: http://goo.gl/CcMypt

Comment: *Print news* means "news obtained from print media". Young people are no longer getting their news from newspapers and magazines.

Comment: @StoneyB But in this way, "print" would become a adjective, it doesn't look grammatical don't you think?

Comment: That's the way English works. Verbs like ***print*** become nouns (*books in **print***), those nouns modify other nouns (***print** media*), adjectives become verbs (***brown** your meat in a skillet*), prepositions become adjectives (***off** flavours*). The whole part-of-speech thing only takes you so far before it breaks down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Print news" is news that is printed on paper. Usually this refers to a physical newspaper (rather than a newspaper you read on the internet). Print news could also refer to a magazine. The important thing is that it is news, printed on paper, using ink.

The article is saying that young people are preferring to read the news online, rather than buying a paper newspaper.

I don't think this is a very common phrase, but that is probably because, as the article says, newspapers themselves are becoming less common. :)